# TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to add something to a dictionary in Python 3 (for the purpose of like creating a username and password). However I'm encountering an error telling me that type does not support item assignment. I'm a noob in programming so please bear with me. I just assumed that adding keys and values in dictionary in python does not allow the use input variables.

```
userlist = dict


def main():
    add_user()
    print(userlist)


def add_user():
    global new_user
    global new_password
    print('Please indicate your desired username')
    new_user = str(input('User: ')).lower
    print('Please indicate your desired password')
    new_password = str(input('Password: '))
    print('Please re-enter your password')
    password_addcheck = str(input('Password:'))
    if password_addcheck == new_password:
        print('Thank you, you are now successfully registered')
        userlist[new_user] = new_password
    else:
        print('Password does not match, please repeat process')
        add_user()


main()
```

Comment: `new_user = str(input('User: ')).lower` should be `new_user = str(input('User: ')).lower()`.

Comment: amusingly, this is not the cause of the error OP posted, although it is a valid comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@loocid is right, but also the first line of your code is wrong:

```
userlist = dict
```

should be

```
userlist = dict()
```

`userlist = dict` assigns the python keyword (and datatype) `dict` to the variable userlist - the error you see actually comes when you try to use the definition `dict` as if it was a dictionary, rather than a keyword that is used to *create* dictionaries.